# How to handle mesh sequences for display in three.js?

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, mesh

all!

I have a sequence of .obj files that represent a baked animation of a mesh.

I've tried importing the sequence with meshfoot script to blender and calculating .mdd point cache, than exporting it as morph animation with io_three, but it didn't work for me. The topology ended up being a mess.

What would be the optimal pipeline to handle mesh animation sequences in three.js?

Cheers!